# Format amount of seconds to minutes and seconds with momentjs

Tags: javascript, format, momentjs

I'd like to use momentjs to use a given amount of seconds (e.g. 65) and format that to minutes and seconds (so in the case of 65 seconds it should format it to '01:05'). I've looked around the momentjs docs and also here but I couldn't quite get to the right solution. I know there's a way to do this with just pure JavaScript, but I'd like to use momentjs for this.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on doing this using `moment.js`, you can do something like this:
Start with a `00:00:00.000` time and add seconds, minutes, etc. to it.
Here is an example:

```js
const result = moment("00:00:00.000", "hh:mm:ss.SSS").add(65, "s").format("mm:ss");
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.14.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

The problem is that since this is the time of a date, when you add `24` hours to it, you'll end up with `00:00:00` instead of `24:00:00`.